# Best way to show all hidden divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several hidden divs inside large div, they can be shown one by one or all at once
It looks like this:

```
<div class="maindiv">
   Print "<a href=javascript:show()>Click here to show all</a>
   <a href="javascript:showhide(document.getElementById('div1'))">Show/hide div1</a>
   <div id="div1" style="display:none;">.....</div>
   <a href="javascript:showhide(document.getElementById('div2'))">Show/hide div2</a>
   <div id="div2" style="display:none;">.....</div>
   ....
</div>
```

showhide() function is ok showing/hiding given div, show() works too but like this:

```
function show(){
   div1.style.display="block";
   div2.style.display="block";
   ...
}
```

so if I'll have 100 divs I'll have to enter it there 100 times
so my question is, how can I find all hidden divs in div with class maindiv and show em other way than enumerate? Or is the way I do ok?

Comment: $("div").show() if you can use jquery

Comment: It's not in your tags so I'll mention, if you don't have an aversion to jquery, jquery can handle this easily.

Comment: Target maindiv and add a class to it, then you can just show all the divs with css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a generic css class name that is defined similarly:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
}
```

Then all you have to do is select the elements that have that class and remove that class. Assuming you are using at least IE9 you can try:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden"); 
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
   divs[i].className = ""; //assuming you only have that class set else you will need to do a search and replace
}
```

If you have to support earlier versions there are other methods that will work to gather all the divs you need such as `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`

Comment: I tried this, expected it working, but for some weird reason its not working for each second div. I will look at it later, no time now...

Comment: `if(i%2==1)i--;` inside loop solved it, just dont know why doesn't it work without it

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PZpP/1/)**

Try this:

**JQuery**

```
$('.maindiv div a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});

$('#showAll').click(function(){
    $('.maindiv div div').show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="maindiv">
   <a href="#" id="showAll">Click here to show all</a>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Show/hide div1</a>
       <div>.....</div>
       <a href="#">Show/hide div2</a>
       <div>.....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.maindiv div a{
    display:block;
}

.maindiv div div{
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: OP did not tag question with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   //You can also write here if condition
   divs[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Should be `display="block"` not `display("block")`

Comment: I have copied that code line from the question. Now I have corrected my above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work

http://jsfiddle.net/rtu75/

```
function show() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("maindiv");
    var l = divs.length;
    for( var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        divs[i].setAttribute("class", "show");
    }        
}
```

In your css

```
.show div {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Added important since you have inline styles

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, try

```
$("*").show();
```

or

```
$(parentElem).find("*").show();
```

or

```
$(":not(:visible)").show();
// This selects "*". Not I expected.
```

See [w3 - css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), [MDN - css pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), and jQuery `$()`, `$().find()`, `$().filter()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw your code below, I saw it's almost work. You need to change id='div1' to class='hid' after that read my below step >> Go down

```html
   <a href="showhide(document.getElementById('div1'))">Show/hide div1</a>
   <div id="div1" style="display:none;">.....</div>
```

Here is my step, I am in same problem but now I can solve this because I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24192071/10618118 then try to solve until done.

Read below,it's my code.It's work as I want.

in My **Style** for CSS be like this

```css
<style>
     .hid {}
</style>
```

Next is My Button to control it hidden or visible, Simple.

```html
<button id="see" type="button" onclick="clickSee();">Show More ...</button>
```

Next step, look at my Javascript Code below, 
I use JQuery 3.2.1 to change function in onclick of button.
when user want to hide or see more 
just click Show More ... or ... Show less, 
Actually it's the same button but user don't know.

If you didn't use JQuery yet and decide to use just copy

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

and paste in `<head></head>`

```js
<script>
    function clickSee() {
       document.getElementById("see").innerHTML = "... Show Less";
       var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hid");
       for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
           divs[i].style.display = "block";
       }
  //I use JQuery
       $("#see").attr("onclick", "clickHide()");
    }

    function clickHide() {
       document.getElementById("see").innerHTML = "Show More ... ";
       var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hid");
       for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
           divs[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       //I use JQuery
       $("#see").attr("onclick", "clickSee()");
   }
</script>
```

If you have any issues just comment below, I will try to help because when done.

There are many way to make your idea work. but I see here is my basic way.

Feel free for new recommendation. Thank you.